# Google Maps - Dynamically Generating Markers on Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I"m new to google maps and am trying to get all the locations that are returned on my search page to appears on the corresponding map but I can't make it work.  I have each listing display their longitude and latitude with the listing and I'm using the code below.  Can someone help me out with this?  It's got to be something simple I'm missing.  Thanks!

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);

    // Multiple Markers

    var markers = [];
     $(".eventCoordinates").each(function() {
        var myLocation = $(this).html();
        markers.push(myLocation);

    });

    // Info Window Content
    var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
        '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' +        '</div>'],
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
        '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
        '</div>']
    ];

    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });

        // Allow each marker to have an info window    
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(14);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

}

 </script>           

            <div id="map_wrapper">
    <div id="map_canvas" class="mapping"></div>
</div>

<div class="event">

<div class="eventCoordinates">51.503454,-0.119562</div>

</div>

<div class="event">

<div class="eventCoordinates">51.499633,-0.124755</div>

</div>
```

Comment: need to see what the html looks like in `$(".eventCoordinates")` that you are converting to markers. Keep in mind it is only a string

Comment: check the very bottom of the code snippet - the html is down there

Comment: need to convert that html to array then ... can use `split(',')` and then each array element will still be string so need to cast to number to pass to maps api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To data from your html you need to convert the html to array of numbers.

Try:

```
$(".eventCoordinates").each(function() {
        // create array of strings
        var myLocation = $(this).html().split(',');
        // convert strings to number
        myLocation[0] = + myLocation[0];
        myLocation[1] = + myLocation[1];
        markers.push(myLocation);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);

    // Multiple Markers
    var markers = [];
    $(".eventCoordinates").each(function () {
        var myLocation = $(this).html().split(',');
        markers.push(['Marker',parseFloat(myLocation[0]),parseFloat(myLocation[1])]);
    });

    // Info Window Content
    var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
        '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' + '</div>'],
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
        '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
        '</div>']
    ];

    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });

        // Allow each marker to have an info window    
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
   var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function (event) {
        this.setZoom(14);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

}
```

```css
.mapping {
            height: 480px;
            width: 640px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div id="map_wrapper">
    <div id="map_canvas" class="mapping"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="event">
        <div class="eventCoordinates">51.503454,-0.119562</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
        <div class="eventCoordinates">51.499633,-0.124755</div>
</div>
```

There is only one change compared to your example, regarding how marker information is extracted from div element:

```
$(".eventCoordinates").each(function() {
    var myLocation = $(this).html();
    markers.push(myLocation);
});
```

replaced with:

```
$(".eventCoordinates").each(function () {
    var myLocation = $(this).html().split(',');
    markers.push(['Marker',parseFloat(myLocation[0]),parseFloat(myLocation[1])]);
});
```